# Changing user's info in Context api using React useState Hooks

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to use Context API to store the user's info after he is logged in, but the setAuth, when I try to set the data says that function "setAuth is not a function"

```
    import { createContext, useState } from "react";

const AuthContext = createContext({});

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [auth, setAuth] = useState(null);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={(auth, setAuth)}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default AuthContext;
```

Login view

```
  const { user, setAuth } = useContext(AuthContext);
  //formik on submit function
    onSubmit: (values) => {
      setAuth(values);  // setAuth is not a function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<AuthContext.Provider value={auth, setAuth}>
  {children}
</AuthContext.Provider>
```

Remove the brackets.

Also, check if LoginView is inside AuthProvider